# Como guardar datos de un Treeview de Tkinter a json correctamente ¿?

Tags: python, json, tkinter, archivo, interfaz-gráfica

Voy a intentar explicarme de la mejor forma posibla para que la pregunta se entienda correctamente...

Tengo el siguiente Treeview en tkinter

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use("alt")
style.configure("Treeview",
    background="silver",
    foreground="green",
    )
style.map('Treeview',
    background=[('selected','#FF1800')])
#Weapons list Treeview
weaponList = ttk.Treeview(root,columns=("Game","Weapon","Down","Up","Left","Right"))
#Setting columns text
weaponList.heading("Game",text="Game")
weaponList.heading("Weapon",text="Weapon")
weaponList.heading("Down",text="Down")
weaponList.heading("Up",text="Up")
weaponList.heading("Left",text="Left")
weaponList.heading("Right",text="Right")

#Show headings (remove extra column)
weaponList['show']='headings'

#Setting columns width and align
weaponList.column("Game",width=60, anchor="center")
weaponList.column("Weapon",width=70, anchor="center")
weaponList.column("Down",width=60, anchor="center")
weaponList.column("Up",width=40, anchor="center")
weaponList.column("Left",width=40, anchor="center")
weaponList.column("Right",width=50, anchor="center")

weaponList.place(x=330,y=120, width=350,height=420)
```

Que se ve tal que así
[image: Treeview]

La pregunta es que al cerrar la aplicación, los valores entrados en el treeview no permanecen al abrir la aplicación de nuevo. Es por eso que quiero guardara la información en un `json`

Para eso tengo la siguiente funcion :

```
def addWeapon():
        if (noAddDefaultWeaponValues()==False):
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Weapon add error','You have entered the defaults values or empty data!')
            return
        #Adding data
        data = {}
        data['weapons'] = []
        data['weapons'].append({
            'game': weaponGameEntry.get(),
            'weapon': weaponNameEntry.get(),
            'down': recoilDownEntry.get(),
            'up': recoilUpEntry.get(),
            'left': recoilLeftEntry.get(),
            'right': recoilRightEntry.get()
        })

        with open('json/weapons.json', 'w') as save:
            json.dump(data, save, indent=4)

        weaponList.insert(parent='', index='end', text="", values=(weaponGameEntry.get(), weaponNameEntry.get(),recoilDownEntry.get(),recoilUpEntry.get(),recoilLeftEntry.get(),recoilRightEntry.get()))

        #Clear boxes when add and insert the default values
        weaponGameEntry.delete(0,END)
        weaponGameEntry.insert(0,"INSERT GAME")
        weaponNameEntry.delete(0,END)
        weaponNameEntry.insert(0,"INSERT WEAPON")
        recoilDownEntry.delete(0,END)
        recoilDownEntry.insert(0,"0")
        recoilUpEntry.delete(0,END)
        recoilUpEntry.insert(0,"0")
        recoilLeftEntry.delete(0,END)
        recoilLeftEntry.insert(0,"0")
        recoilRightEntry.delete(0,END)
        recoilRightEntry.insert(0,"0")
```

El problema con esto es que tan solo añade el último registro en vez de añadir ambos.

Por ejemplo, imaginemos que añado los siguientes registros :
[image: Ejemplo de los registros añadidos]

Pues el `json` se ve tal que así:

```
{
    "weapons": [
        {
            "game": "GAME2",
            "weapon": "WEAPON2",
            "down": "0",
            "up": "0",
            "left": "0",
            "right": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

En vez de :

```
{
    "weapons": [
        {
            "game": "GAME1",
            "weapon": "WEAPON1",
            "down": "0",
            "up": "0",
            "left": "0",
            "right": "0"
        },
        {
            "game": "GAME2",
            "weapon": "WEAPON2",
            "down": "0",
            "up": "0",
            "left": "0",
            "right": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Estoy agradecido de escuchar cualquier tipo de sugerencias y soluciones. Muchas gracias de antemano, si el código es complicado de leer estoy activo en los comentarios.

Gracias !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si acaso a alguien le sirviera le repuesta publico mi solucion...

Modificando la funcion de mi pregunta para guardar los datos correctamente al json, primero se lee la información ya existente y después se escribe en el archivo.

```
#Add weapon to ListBox when click the AddWeapon Button
def addWeapon():
        if (noAddDefaultWeaponValues()==False):
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror('Weapon add error','You have entered the defaults values or empty data!')
            return
        #Adding data to json
        with open('json/weapons.json', 'r') as save:
            weaponsList = json.loads(save.read())['weapons'] 
            weaponsList.append({
                    'game': weaponGameEntry.get(),
                    'weapon': weaponNameEntry.get(),
                    'down': recoilDownEntry.get(),
                    'up': recoilUpEntry.get(),
                    'left': recoilLeftEntry.get(),
                    'right': recoilRightEntry.get()
                    })
            weaponsDict = {}
            weaponsDict['weapons'] = weaponsList
        with open('json/weapons.json', 'w') as write:
                json.dump(weaponsDict, write, indent=4)

        weaponList.insert(parent='', index='end', text="", values=(weaponGameEntry.get(), weaponNameEntry.get(),recoilDownEntry.get(),recoilUpEntry.get(),recoilLeftEntry.get(),recoilRightEntry.get()))

        #Clear boxes when add and insert the default values
        weaponGameEntry.delete(0,END)
        weaponGameEntry.insert(0,"INSERT GAME")
        weaponNameEntry.delete(0,END)
        weaponNameEntry.insert(0,"INSERT WEAPON")
        recoilDownEntry.delete(0,END)
        recoilDownEntry.insert(0,"0")
        recoilUpEntry.delete(0,END)
        recoilUpEntry.insert(0,"0")
        recoilLeftEntry.delete(0,END)
        recoilLeftEntry.insert(0,"0")
        recoilRightEntry.delete(0,END)
        recoilRightEntry.insert(0,"0")
```

***AÑADIDO*** Función donde se insertan los datos del `json` al Treeview al abrir la aplicación (se puede pulir el codigo pero no tiene mala sintaxis).

```
#Inserting the already existing weapons to the listbox
def insertExistingWeapons():
        with open('json/weapons.json', 'r') as read:
                weaponsList = json.loads(read.read())['weapons']
                weaponsDict = {}
                weaponsDict['weapons'] = weaponsList

        for weapon in weaponsList:
                weaponList.insert(parent='', index='end', text="", values=(weapon['game'],weapon['weapon'],weapon['down'],weapon['up'],weapon['left'],weapon['right']))
```